# 10e5 == 10^5 is not true in MATLAB, why?

Tags: matlab, exponentiation

If you type in

```
    10e5 == 10^5  
  ans =  
    logical  
     0
```

so 10e5 does NOT mean 10 to the power of 5 but it means 10 to the power of 6.

```
10e5 == 10^6  
ans =  
  logical  
   1
```

What does 10e5 mean then? Is it somewhere in the documentation? I just can't seem to find it, I've been looking for it for quite some time now.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 10e5 == 10*10^5 == 10^6

Comment: Perhaps you need to have a look at the scientific E notation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation?wprov=sfla1

Comment: [Scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). 10e5 is 10 + 5 zeroes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"1e5" means "one times ten to the power of 5", so "10e5" means "10 times ten to the power of 5" which is equal to 10^6 or 1e6.